# Adding help option for function

Tags: function, arguments

I have the following function that print `NUM` lines from the beginning of a set of files.

The command (function, script, whatever) accepts a variable number of arguments, and I would like to reserve one special option for "tell me how to use you", the traditional choices being "help", "-h", "-?" and "--help".

```
headrc ()
{
    # Prints first set of lines from named files.
    # $1 NUM  Number of lines to print
    # $2 DIR  Directory

    num=$1
    dir=$2
      
    find "$dir" \( -name \*.org -o -name \*.texi \)  \
      | xargs head -n "$num";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it manually, but using `getopt` would be more useful moving forward.  Consider for example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Prints first set of lines from named files.
# $1 NUM  Number of lines to print
# $2 DIR  Directory
headrc() {
    eval set -- $(getopt --name "${FUNCNAME[0]}" --options h --longoptions help -- "${@}")

    while [[ "${1}" != "--" ]]; do
        case "${1}" in
        -h | --help)
            printf "Usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]} [-h|--help] <args>\n"
            return 1
            ;;
        *)
            printf "Unknown option: ${1}\n"
            ;;
        esac

        shift # Shift off option
    done
    shift # Shift off --

    local -r num="${1}"
    local -r dir="${2}"

    find "${dir}" \( -name \*.org -o -name \*.texi \) | xargs head -n "${num}";
}
```

The `getopt` tool takes the existing arguments (`${@}`) and the options that you give it, and reorders them such that all the options come first, then a `--`, then everything else.  The `--options` option specifies the single-character options and the `--longoptions` specifies the "long" (multi-character) options.

For example:

```
$ getopt --options fh --longoptions file,help -- a b c -f d e --help g
 -f --help -- 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'g'
```

Note that `getopt` supports options with parameters, but since you don't need that here, I didn't cover that aspect of the tool.

The `eval set --` updates the arguments to the given values, rewriting what the function sees as its arguments to the output of `getopt`.

The `while` loop processes the options; the options stop when it encounters `--`.  If is see `-h` or `--help`, it prints a help message and returns.  Each time it processes the loop it uses `shift` to "shift off" the first argument.

Once it finds the `--` it stops looping, and shifts off that argument.

You're now left with everything that came *after* the options, so you can use the positional arguments like you did before.

Comment: How can I skip the `find` command if I pass `-h` ?

Comment: +1 but it's worth pointing out that only the version of `getopt` from `util-linux` is safe to use (this is pretty much the standard/default `getopt` on linux but not on other systems).  Other versions have serious problems (e.g. can't handle empty arguments or args containing whitespace) and should not be used.

Comment: @Pietru What I've shown does skip the `find` if you pass `-h`; see the `return 1`.